# AngularJS: Execute function of directive on pageload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angular-translate

This is my directive that handles popovers. I do use [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service) to translate the text in different languages:

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .directive('tariffPopover', [
    '$translate', 
    '$rootScope', 
    function ($translate, $rootScope) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    translateText: '@tariffPopover'
  },
  template:
    '<span ng-transclude></span>' +
    '&nbsp;' +
    '<span popover-placement="right" ' +
    '      uib-popover-html="text" ' +
    '      popover-trigger="mouseenter" ' +
    '      class="fa fa-info-circle">' +
    '</span>',
  controller: function ($scope) {
    $translate($scope.translateText).then(function (translatedText) {
      $scope.text = translatedText;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
      $translate($scope.translateText).then(function (translatedText) {
        $scope.text = translatedText;
      });
    });

  }
};
}]);
```

The translation gets executed when the language changes with `$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess')`. However this does not execute when the page loads, so I added the lines to translate the text again in the controller:

```
  controller: function ($scope) {
    $translate($scope.translateText).then(function (translatedText) {
      $scope.text = translatedText;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
      $translate($scope.translateText).then(function (translatedText) {
        $scope.text = translatedText;
      });
    });
```

Is there a way to execute the translation on pageload without having code duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is avoid a copy-paste, then I think it is a better object-oriented practice to wrap the duplicated code in a named function rather than using an anonymous function. This way it can be reused.

```
controller: function ($scope) {

  var translate = function(){
     $translate($scope.translateText).then(function (translatedText) {
         $scope.text = translatedText;
    });
  }

  $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', translate);

  //execute the translation when the controller loads
  translate();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

`$translateChangeSuccess` with

`$locationChangeSuccess` to make it effective when the page/location is changed.

Also you can use `$viewContentLoaded` if you wish to have it after the content in the page is loaded.

Hope it will be helpful..!

Comment: can you please show me the error which you get in console?

Comment: There is none. It seems `$locationChangeSuccess` is never fired.

Comment: can you please add the fiddle for the same? so that i can have a look of it.